# confused about lazy evaluation in Idris

Tags: idris

Reading and playing around with some examples from the official Idris tutorial has left me a bit confused regarding lazy evaluation.

As stated in the tutorial Idris uses eager evaluation, and they go on to give an example where this would not be appropriate

```
ifThenElse : Bool -> a -> a -> a
ifThenElse True  t e = t
ifThenElse False t e = e
```

And they then proceed to show an example using lazy evaluation

```
ifThenElse : Bool -> Lazy a -> Lazy a -> a
ifThenElse True  t e = t
ifThenElse False t e = e
```

I like to try things out while reading, so I created an inefficient Fibonacci function to test out the non-lazy and lazy `ifThenElse`.

```
fibo : Nat -> Nat
fibo Z = Z
fibo (S Z) = S Z
fibo (S(S Z)) = S(S Z)
fibo (S(S(S n))) = fibo (S(S n)) + fibo (S n)

-- the non lazy
ifThenElse1 : Bool -> (t: a) -> (f: a) -> a
ifThenElse1 False t f = f
ifThenElse1 True t f = t

-- should be slow when applied to True
iftest1 : Bool -> Nat
iftest1 b = ifThenElse1 b (fibo 5) (fibo 25)

-- the lazy
ifThenElse2 : Bool -> (t: Lazy a) -> (f: Lazy a) -> a
ifThenElse2 False t f = f
ifThenElse2 True t f = t

-- should be fast when applied to True
iftest2 : Bool -> Nat
iftest2 b = ifThenElse2 b (fibo 5) (fibo 25)
```

Given that Idris should be performing eager evaluation, I would expect the execution of `iftest1` to be slowed down by `(fibo 25)` even when applied to True. However, both `iftest1` and `iftest2` execute very fast when applied to True. So maybe my understanding of lazyness/eagerness is fundamentally flawed?

What is a good example to observe the difference between lazyness and eagerness in Idris?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably tried `iftest1` and `iftest2` from the Idris REPL. [The REPL uses different evaluation order than compiled code](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/faq/faq.html#evaluation-at-the-repl-doesn-t-behave-as-i-expect-what-s-going-on):

> Being a fully dependently typed language, Idris has two phases where it evaluates things, compile-time and run-time. At compile-time it will only evaluate things which it knows to be total (i.e. terminating and covering all possible inputs) in order to keep type checking decidable. The compile-time evaluator is part of the Idris kernel, and is implemented in Haskell using a HOAS (higher order abstract syntax) style representation of values. Since everything is known to have a normal form here, the evaluation strategy doesn’t actually matter because either way it will get the same answer, and in practice it will do whatever the Haskell run-time system chooses to do.
>
> The REPL, for convenience, uses the compile-time notion of evaluation.

Comment: So I should be able to see the difference for compiled code? I just tried to create a main function which takes some user input which then is used to create a boolean for the `iftest1` function. I compiled the file to an executable, ran it and gave it some input. However it seems that `iftest1` still behaves as if it was lazy. I also tried to make the Fibonacci function non-total, but it didn't change anything. What would be a better example to observe the lazyness vs eagerness? (if it is possible at all to create such an example)

Comment: Try to make the `b : Bool` depend to some input, so `iftest1 b` cannot get reduced at compile-time.